# Need to convert string with list values to Map type in scala

Tags: string, scala, dictionary

I have following string values with various formats.

```
val str = "column: [year,id], condition: >10"
val str = "column: year, condition: ==1984"
val str = "column: id"
val str = "column: [UPDT_DT,id],condition: == 1.0"
```

I need to convert these to map type key value pairs.

Expected output:

```
val str_map = Map("column" -> ["year","id"]),("condition" -> ">10")
val str_map = Map("column" -> "year"), ("condition" -> "==1984")
val str_map = Map("column" -> "id")
val str_map = Map("column: -> ["UPDT_DT","id"]),("condition" -> "== 1.0")
```

I tried below code:

```
val str_map = str.split(",").map(row => row.split(":")).map(kv => (kv(0), kv(1).trim)).toMap
```

This causing error because list value has `,`. Need help! I am mainly interested only in `column` values. How to extract the `column` values efficiently.

Comment: How do you distinguish between comma as part of a value vs. comma as a separator?
If "column" and "condition" are the only two possibilities, you are better off looking for those tokens explicitly.

Comment: I am mainly interested only in column values. How to extract the column values?

Comment: Should the value be a string like `"id"` or an array like `["year","id"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
"""(\w+):\s*(.+?)(?=(,\s*\w+:|$))""".r
  .findAllMatchIn(str)
  .map { m => m.group(1) -> m.group(2) }
  .toMap
```

This will work *unless* some of the values happen to contain a substring looking like a word, followed by a semi-colon (like `foo:`)

Or if the only two keys are 'column' and 'condition', and you are only interested in the former as you mentioned in the comment, then
this:

```
str.replaceAll("""(column:\s*|,\s*condition.*)""", "")
```

will give you the value for `column` (unless it happens to contain "condition:" as a substring).